# Symmetries of a spherical harmonic basis

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, symmetry, change-of-basis, spherical-harmonics

I am interested in constructing a set of functions $Z_l^m$ which are linear combinations of spherical harmonics up to a maximum degree $L$,
$$
Z_k^n(\theta,\phi) = \sum_{l=0}^L \sum_{m=-l}^l \alpha_{kl}^{nm} Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)
$$
or in matrix-vector notation,
$$
\mathbf{Z}(\theta,\phi) = A \mathbf{Y}(\theta,\phi)
$$
where $\mathbf{Z},\mathbf{Y}$ are vectors of length $N = (L+1)^2$, and $A_{(kn),(lm)} = \alpha_{kl}^{nm}$. Now, the spherical harmonics have the following nice properties:

1. $\left< Y_k^n, Y_l^m \right> = \int d\Omega Y_k^n Y_l^{m*} = \delta_{kl} \delta_{nm}$
2. $Y_l^{-m} = (-1)^m Y_l^{m*}$

I would like the new functions $Z_l^m$ to satisfy these properties also. The first condition leads to
$$
I = \int d\Omega \mathbf{Z} \mathbf{Z}^{\dagger} = A \left( \int d\Omega \mathbf{Y} \mathbf{Y}^{\dagger} \right) A^{\dagger} = A A^{\dagger}
$$
which means $A$ must be a unitary matrix, $A \in U(N)$ in order for the $Z_l^m$ to be orthonormal.

The second condition is what I am having trouble with. The condition $Z_k^{-n} = (-1)^n Z_k^{n*}$ leads to the following condition on the $A$ matrix,
$$
\alpha_{kl}^{-n,m} = (-1)^{n+m} \alpha_{kl}^{n,-m*}
$$
**My question is, does there exist some subset of $U(N)$ which satisfies this condition above**? I would like to determine all possible unitary matrices $A$ which satisfy this symmetry condition above. Certainly $A = I$ satifies the condition, but I would like to find nontrivial solutions. How would one start to attack this problem?

Comment: It seems like this group must contain $SO(3)$ as a subgroup, since any rotation leaves $l$ invariant, and the new functions that arise as a consequence of the rotation are themselves spherical harmonics but around a different axis.

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer to my question, but I have managed to show that all matrices $A \in U(N)$ which satisfy
$$
\alpha_{kl}^{-n,m} = (-1)^{n+m} \alpha_{kl}^{n,-m*}
$$
form a **subgroup** of $U(N)$. To prove closure, assume that $A,B$ are unitary matrices satisfying the above condition and let $C = AB$. Then,
\begin{align}
C_{(kn)(lm)} = A_{(kn)(uv)} B_{(uv)(lm)}
\end{align}
where I use the Einstein summation convention over $(uv)$. Then,
\begin{align}
C_{(k,-n)(lm)} &= A_{(k,-n)(uv)} B_{(uv)(lm)} \\
&= (-1)^{n+v} A_{(kn)(u,-v)}^{*} B_{(uv)(lm)} \\
&= (-1)^{n+v} A_{(kn)(u,-v)}^{*} (-1)^{v+m} B_{(u,-v)(l,-m)}^{*} \\
&= (-1)^{n+m} A_{(kn)(uv)}^{*} B_{(uv)(l,-m)}^{*} \\
&= (-1)^{n+m} C_{(kn)(l,-m)}^{*}
\end{align}
which proves that $C$ is in the subgroup. To show that the inverse is also in the subgroup, note that $A^{-1} = A^{\dagger}$. Then,
\begin{align}
(A^{\dagger})_{(kn)(lm)} &= A_{(lm)(kn)}^{*}
\end{align}
We then have,
\begin{align}
(A^{\dagger})_{(k,-n)(lm)} &= A_{(lm)(k,-n)}^{*} \\
&= (-1)^{m+n} A_{(l,-m)(kn)} \\
&= (-1)^{m+n} (A^{\dagger})_{(kn)(l,-m)}^{*}
\end{align}
which proves that $A^{-1} = A^{\dagger}$ belongs to the subgroup. So the search for matrices satisfying my condition can be restricted to subgroups of $U(N)$. I still don't know how to actually find this subgroup...

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to be sure there exist nontrivial elements of the subgroup I seek. If we define
$$
G_L := \left\{ A \in U((L+1)^2) : A_{(k,-n)(lm)} = (-1)^{n+m} A_{(kn)(l,-m)}^{*}\right\}
$$
then it is easy to see that $G_0 = \left\{ \pm I \right\}$ so the $L=0$ case is trivial. However, $L=1$ is more interesting. Using the symmetry condition,
we find that for $n=0, m=0$,
$$
A_{(k0)(l0)} = A_{(k0)(l0)}^{*}
$$
so these matrix entries must be real. The structure of a general element of $G_1$ will look like:
$$
G_1 =
\begin{pmatrix}
a & \alpha & c & -\alpha^{*} \\
\gamma & \epsilon & \delta & \eta \\
d & \beta & b & -\beta^{*} \\
-\gamma^{*} & \eta^{*} & -\delta^{*} & \epsilon^{*}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\epsilon,\delta,\eta \in \mathbb{C}$. Here, I have ordered the matrix entries as $(0,0), (1,-1), (1,0), (1,1)$. There is also the additional constrant that the above matrix must be unitary which is a bit more complicated. However, if we consider diagonal matrices, we immediately see that the following matrix is in $G_1$,
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\pm 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & e^{i \theta} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \pm 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & e^{-i \theta}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
for any $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$. This result shows that there are indeed nontrivial elements of $G_L$ for $L > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Any three-dimensional rotation of space should satisfy the constraints, because a rotation is unitary, it doesn't mix $l$ subspaces, and the result within each $l$ subspace is to make a new set of spherical harmonics corresponding to a different axis, and hence, by transforming $A=I$ under the transformation, you get a non-trivial $A$.  To effect the transformation, we rely on the definition of the [Wigner-$D$ matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_D-matrix), which are unitary matrices satisfying
$$
D^{(l)}_{m_1m_2}=(-1)^{m1-m2}(D^{(l)}_{-m_1,-m_2})^*,
$$
where $l$, $m_1$, and $m_2$ are angular momentum quantum numbers.  In particular, for $l=0$ and $l=1$, these matrices are
$$
D^{(0)}=[1],
$$
and
$$
D^{(1)} =
\begin{bmatrix}
 e^{-i \phi -i \psi } \cos ^2\left(\frac{\theta }{2}\right) & -\sqrt{2} e^{-i \psi } \cos
   \left(\frac{\theta }{2}\right) \sin \left(\frac{\theta }{2}\right) & e^{i \phi -i \psi
   } \sin ^2\left(\frac{\theta }{2}\right) \\
 \sqrt{2} e^{-i \phi } \cos \left(\frac{\theta }{2}\right) \sin \left(\frac{\theta
   }{2}\right) & \cos (\theta ) & -\sqrt{2} e^{i \phi } \cos \left(\frac{\theta
   }{2}\right) \sin \left(\frac{\theta }{2}\right) \\
 e^{i \psi -i \phi } \sin ^2\left(\frac{\theta }{2}\right) & \sqrt{2} e^{i \psi } \cos
   \left(\frac{\theta }{2}\right) \sin \left(\frac{\theta }{2}\right) & e^{i \phi +i \psi
   } \cos ^2\left(\frac{\theta }{2}\right) \\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
The quantities $\psi$, $\theta$, and $\phi$ are Euler angles, yielding a parameterization of all three-dimensional rotations.  These $D$-matrices are unitary representations of both $SU(2)$ and $SO(3)$, and this implies (I think), that these groups are at least *subgroups* of the group that you are looking for, and I *suspect* that this is actually *all* such transformations (up to including an inversion in space, which might work.

In general, one can make the matrix you are looking for by just constructing the block-diagonal matrix with $D^{(0)}$ in the first block, $D^{(1)}$ in the second block, and so on.

---

Note that for the case of $L=1$, the matrix constructed here has eigenvalues 1, 1, and $e^{\pm i\theta}$ if $\psi=0$ and $\phi=0$, so one of the matrices constructed in one of the other answers is a special case of this.  The other is likely the corresponding one from $O(3)$ that also has an inversion in space.

---

Now, I suspect that this is somewhat uninteresting, in the sense that all we're really doing is constructing new spherical harmonics about a different axis and then just adding them directly.  In other words, the functions thus created are essentially the same as the case where $A=I$, except that we've rotated the $z$-axis.  What would be interesting if there existed such matrices for which spherical harmonics of different $l$'s *mixed* with each other, i.e. $A_{kl,mn}\neq0$ when $k\neq l$, but I have been unable to construct those.

---

Incidentally, if you have access to *Mathematica*, the Wigner $D$ matrices are implemented as

```
WignerD[{l, m1, m2}, ψ, θ, ϕ]
```

where of course, `l` is a non-negative integer, and `m1` and `m2` are integers between `-l` and `l`.